# For loop is replicating dataframe 500 times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I dont know what I do wrong, but the output of the code below is replicating it selves 500 times. Is there probably a more elegant way to concat multiple dataframes?

```py
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import glob

path = r"C:\Users\A\Downloads\*.xls"

list_data = []

for loop in tqdm(glob.glob(path, recursive=True)):
    data = pd.read_excel(loop, sheet_name="Summary")

    data["Batch"] = data.iloc[0, 2]

    list_data.append(data)

final_data = pd.concat(list_data)[['Batch']]

print(final_data)
```

Comment: for concatation dataframes you can use `merge` method between multiple df

Comment: You should provide a short example of input, current output and expected output.

Comment: What is in `data.iloc[0, 2]`? Why do you need to store the entire dataframes if you are going to extract just the `Batch` column? And we cannot help you without an example. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with a _small_ sample input data and the corresponding expected result.